# Is there any way to record audio output by using command line?

Tags: raspbian, audio, linux, alsa

I'm trying to record the audio output of my pi but i can't find any good solution.

I tried to use `arecord` but it fails because I don't have any input devices. Because of this my idea was to redirect the sound of the output to a virtual audio input card.

Is this idea possible? If so, will I still hear the sound on my speakers? 
If this is not working, do you have another idea how I could do it?

Comment: Try `modprobe snd-aloop`.

Comment: thanks, this creats a new device in alsamixer "loopback". but alsamixer tells me that "This device does not have any controls". arecord keeps saying: "arecord: main:682: audio open error: No such file or directory" any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You have to use the correct parameters for `arecord`. But the aloop device will not play anything to your real output; maybe you should PulseAudio.

Comment: It's probably not Pi specific. Maybe U&L.SE would be of better help.